# Singleton not getting Referenced in Start() Function after Scene Change

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, singleton

I am trying to understand why I am getting a missing reference exception after a scene change when using singletons.

So, I have two GameObjects in the first scene. A main camera with a GameManager script attached and another shop object with a Purchaser script attached. Both scripts are also singletons created like this for example:

```
public static Purchaser Instance

    void Awake(){
        Instance = this
    }
```

They then both reference each other in the Start() function, again like this for example:

```
    void Start(){
        game = GameManager.Instance
    }
```

Before a scene change, both scripts use each others singleton references to call methods from one another and everything seems to be working fine. Once I change scenes neither of those objects is in the next scene so they both get destroyed. However, once I go back to the main scene I receive a missing reference exception when the purchaser script attempts to call a method from GameManager using the singleton reference it gets from Start(), that changes the text of a text object attached to the main camera. This function is called after a button is pressed that is attached to the shop object that calls this function in the Purchaser script:

```
UpdateMoney(){
    game.UpdateMoney(100);
}
```

I read around and was seeing that this may be because Start() will only being called once throughout the whole game run. Which meant the GameManger singleton instance of the Purchaser script was still the old one from before the scenes changed and that instance was destroyed. But, I just tested to see if this was true by putting a debug log in each scripts Start() function, and saw that after each scene change back to the main scene the debug log would go through from both scripts Start(). So, would it be right to say Start() is only ever called once for the life of script but not for the whole game run right? Shouldn't this also mean that once the game changes back to the main scene and both GameObjects are created again, the Purchaser script should now have an updated reference to the newly created GameManager script since Start() was called again?

What I also found was that this worked instead of using the game reference in UpdateMoney():

```
UpdateMoney(){
    GameManager.Instance.UpdateMoney(100);
}
```

So, why does this work instead of using the game reference retrieved in Start()? Does this mean when Start() is called GameManager.Instance is still the old GameManager.Instance which is why game = GameManager.Instance does not work? Sorry this is very wordy. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand, you have a singleton made in the main scene. The game object where the singleton is attached to is destroyed after switching scenes.

First of all, is there a reason why you need the singleton to be a MonoBehaviour and attached to a game object? Because you can just make a class with

```
private static MyClass instance = null
public static MyClass Instance
{
    get {
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new MyClass();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

This way, your singleton will always have a value and can be passed thru scenes unless instance is set to null.

Second, `Start()` is called once only. However, I encountered issues before that if the MonoBehaviour is attached to a disabled game object, the `Start()` will not be called. You can check if this is what's happening to you when you switch back to the main scene.

Third, if you really need the singleton to be a MonoBehaviour, you can use `DontDestroyOnLoad(instance.gameObject)` so the game object of the singleton will not be destroyed even after a scene switch. However. I assume the game objects are set on the scene. If it is not from a prefab, you can just do something like this

```
private static MyClass instance = null;
public static MyClass Instance
{
    get {
        if(instance == null){
            GameObject inst = new GameObject("MyClass Singleton");
            instance = inst.AddComponent<MyClass>();
            DontDestroyOnLoad(inst);
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

If you do this, then you can remove the preset game objects from the main scene and let the first call to `MyClass.Instance` make the game object for you.

Lastly, if you do not want to do that, you should set `instance = null;` on the game object's `OnDestroy()` so that when you enter the main scene, the new instances will be set to the singleton. This would mean the singleton will not have a value after you switch scenes outside of the main scene.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, you are correct in assuming that the game Objects are set in scene and not prefabs. Sorry for not clarifying. I will try your suggestions and get back to you. Also, are you saying that  Start() will only be called once for a script no matter if it is destroyed on scene change?

Comment: Start() will be called once per instance. So on your first load of main scene, the Start() will be called. After switching to another scene, that instance will be destroyed so OnDestroy() will be called. When you switch back to the main scene Start() will be called again but on the new game object instance.

Comment: By the way, this also means that in the new instance all variable values will reset. Let us say you have an `int coins = 0;`, once the new Singleton instance is created, the coins value will be set to 0 again and not the last coins value you have modified from the previous instance unless you have saved it somewhere and loads it on Start()